# Homology groups (?) of some quotient of $\Bbb{R}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Here is a question from Hatcher (2.2.19):

[image]

I assume that those $H_i$'s are homology groups, Hatcher denotes both the chain complexes and the homology groups by $H$ (I will denote the chain complexes by $C_i$).

$\dots \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}} C_n(\Bbb{R}P^n/\Bbb{R}P^m) \xrightarrow{d_n} C_{n-1}(\Bbb{R}P^{n-1}/\Bbb{R}P^m)\xrightarrow{d_{n-1}} \dots \xrightarrow{d_{m+1}} C_m(\Bbb{R}P^m/\Bbb{R}P^m) \xrightarrow{d_m} 0$

All of them are isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$. So now we need to compute the $d_i$'s by the cellular boundary formula:

[image]

The degree of the map is $2$ when $n$ is even and $0$ when $n$ is odd. So we have groups $\Bbb{Z}$ and $2\Bbb{Z}$ and their quotient etc. It's easy to find the $\ker{d_n}/\operatorname{Im}d_{n+1}$.

But this calculation is very similar to the calculation of the homology groups of $\Bbb{R}P^n$, which is already given in the book. So is there something wrong? Is there some part I should be extra careful?

Comment: Why are you reducing the index of the $\mathbb{R}P^n$s in each chain group? It's not clear where this 'chain complex' (if it even is a chain complex) is coming from. My hint for answering the question would be to first write down the standard CW-structure for $\mathbb{R}P^n$ (with one cell in each dimension) and then also give a way of constructing $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$ from $\mathbb{R}P^n$ using this CW structure.

Comment: The chain groups actually look like $C_n(X^n, X^{n-1})$ so this is what I was trying to say. Yes there is one cell in each dimension so the degree of the map (composition of attaching map and quotient map) is therefore either 2 or 0

Comment: Oh I see my misunderstanding. You should really use $H_n$ instead of $C_n$ because the groups in the chain complex are the homology groups of the pairs $(X^n,X^{n-1})$ for a filtration $X^{\bullet}$ of the space $X$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, now I get why he uses $H_n$ instead.